# Is there a command to show files that have been deprecated by Debian packages?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

My issue born from a recurrent situation, example: I have found a file (/etc/modprobe.d/radeon-kms.conf) on a recently updated Debian installation and I've noticed that shoulnd't exists anymore (xserver-xorg-video-radeon package have removed that file since 2015)
File still exists at its path.

So, when I do the command

```
dpkg -S /etc/modprobe.d/radeon-kms.conf
```

dpkg attributes it to the package xserver-xorg-video-radeon and

```
dpkg -L xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

showing that path at the end of the list generated as output.

But this file isn't part of a recent package
Indeed, on another installation, more fresh but equally updated, this not happens. dpkg -L xserver-xorg-video-radeon  doesn't show that file in its list.

How can I find other mismatching from files declared as owned by a package and files really contained by a package?
Or, alternately, how can I querying dpkg/apt to know that a path is still covered by the original package?

Answer (score 0):

The file is not owned by a package. File can be created by package installer, but after that it is just a file. The package remover goes  by the list of files mentioned in the package.

And if the new version of a package does not know about some file which was part of previous version of the same package - that is it. Unless you learn that yourself from some other means (historical documentation or finding that old version of the package) - you have a true orphan.

You can, however, get a list of files in an existing package:

```
dpkg --listfiles <package>
```

By running this for all installed packages you can get a list of files you must keep. So subtracting that list from the list of files you actually have you can get a list of potential orphans. But are they true ones or were these files written by some application (as configuration file, as some data file or even file from different package) - that would be a mystery to solve.

Comment: dpkg listing all existing files, currently existing and dropped. Because apt/dpkg must be able to clean all when user request a remove with purge on that package.
Indeed, if I had files that are not part of any package, during a purge apt should notifying me that a directory could not be removed because contains other files.
My question is about how to get a diff between the list of files attributed at a package and the real list of files contained in that package.